# Trying to detect if the scrollbar is at bottom, but what is wrong with this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to make the div output scroll to the bottom on each keystroke, only if the input textarea is scrolled to the bottom:

```
$("#inp").keyup(function () {
    if ((this == [0].scrollHeight)) {
        $("#out").scrollTop($('#out')[0].scrollHeight);
    }
})
```

Comment: see `== [0].` in your code. you've missed something while posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

That was a silly attempt. I did this instead, much better:

```
$('#inp').scroll(function (){
    $('#out').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
})
```

I didn't think about .scroll getting affected by the cursorposition. Not only does the output div scroll to the bottom (when needed as I wanted), but both "views" are synchronized, so it scrolls where the focus should be everywhere. I don't know how effective this code is, but it works.